# Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null. Getting this error while using link tag

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am fairly new to React and I am facing this problem.
I am using NPM version: 10.4.0 and NodeJs Version: v20.11.0

> Cannot destructure property 'basename' of
> 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.
>
> TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of
> 'react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useContext(...)' as it is null.

I am trying to use `Link` tag in `Navbar` component

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

App.js

```
// import logo from "./logo.svg";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import TextForm from "./components/TextForm";
import Alert from "./components/alert";
import { useState } from "react";
import { createBrowserRouter, RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./components/about";

function App() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
      alert: message,
      type: type,
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(null);
    }, 1500);
  };

  const Router = createBrowserRouter([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: (
        <TextForm alert={showAlert} heading="Enter your Text to analyze" />
      ),
    },
    { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
  ]);

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar title="Website" about="About" />
      <Alert alert={alert} />
      <div className="container">
        <RouterProvider router={Router} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar(props) {
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <a className="navbar-brand" href="/">
            {props.title}
          </a>
          <button
            className="navbar-toggler"
            type="button"
            data-bs-toggle="collapse"
            data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-expanded="false"
            aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul className="navbar-nav">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link
                  className="nav-link active"
                  aria-current="page"
                  to="/about">
                  about
                </Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  );
}

// Setting the type of the props
Navbar.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  about: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
// setting the default value of the props
Navbar.defaultProps = { title: "Default Title", about: "Default About" };
```

and this is the complete error:
[image: Error]

Is there anything that I need to add in my Index.js to resolve this issue or is there a problem in the logic that I am using.

Answer (score 2):

The `Navbar`, and `Link` components specifically, are rendered ***outside*** the router context provided by `RouterProvider`.

`Navbar` should be rendered within `RouterProvider`. You can create a layout route component that renders `Navbar` and an `Outlet` for the nested routes.

You will want to also move the `router` declaration outside the `App` component on its own so it is not redeclared each time `App` rerenders, e.g. to provide a stable `router` reference to `RouterProvider`.

Example:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
  Outlet
} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import "./App.css";
import TextForm from "./components/TextForm";
import Alert from "./components/alert";
import About from "./components/about";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar title="Website" about="About" />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    element: <AppLayout />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/",
        element: (
          <TextForm alert={showAlert} heading="Enter your Text to analyze" />
        ),
      },
      { path: "/about", element: <About /> },
    ],
  },
);

function App() {
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (alert, type) => {
    setAlert({ alert, type });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(null);
    }, 1500);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Alert alert={alert} />
      <div className="container">
        <RouterProvider router={router} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the `BrowserRouter` needs to be at the `root` level of the Application. Instead of `createBrowserRouter` use `BrowserRouter` Component. [Refer](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router)

```
//Your imports

function App() {
  // Rest of your Code

  // Remove createBrowserRouter instead use BrowserRouter Component

  return (
    <>
      <BrowserRouter>
         <Navbar title="Website" about="About" />
         <Alert alert={alert} />
         <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<TextForm alert={showAlert} heading="Enter your Text to analyze" />} />
            <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
         </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: By the above mentioned method, I am able to run the application but in the docs it is mentioned that BrowserRouter does not support data API's and therefore createBrowserRouter should be used.

https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router#using-v64-data-apis

Answer (score 0):

**React Project:**
Wrap your App by BrowserRouter. That is, your index file shall be:

```
import App from "./App";
import "./index.css";
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')  
)
```

**Gatsby Project:**
Check your link import. It shall be:
`import {Link} from 'gatsby';`

and not:
`import {Link} from "react-router-dom";`